# Почему эта реализация quicksort на C++ работает медленно. Длина вектора до 10 в 5, а ограничение по времени до 0.4 сек

Tags: c++, сортировка

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> a;

int partition(int start, int end) {
    int pivot = a[end], pindex = start;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (a[i] <= pivot) {
            swap(a[i], a[pindex]);
            pindex++;
        }
    }
    swap(a[end], a[pindex]);

    return pindex;
}

void quicksort(int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) {
        return;
    }
    int pivot = partition(start, end);
    quicksort(start, pivot - 1);
    quicksort(pivot + 1, end);
}

int main() {
    int n, x;
    string s;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> x;
        a.push_back(x);
    }
    quicksort(0, (int)a.size() - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Работает медленно всегда? Или иногда?

Comment: Quicksort имеет право работать медленно (за квадрат) для некоторых массивов. Подумайте каким должне быть массив, чтобы ваш алгоритм работал как можно медленнее.